# in R : selecting the columns in a data frame function of the numerical values in a line

Tags: r

Please may I ask for a suggestion:

Considering a data frame in R, that contains the numerical values for gene expression:

```
x <- data.frame(TTT=c(0,1,0,0),
                TTA=c(0,1,1,0),
                ATA=c(1,0,0,0),
                gene=c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4"))
```

How could I select only the COLUMNS where the value of a GENE (a ROW) is non-zero?

thank you!

-- bogdan

Comment: `x[apply(x, 1, function(w) !all(w[1:3] == 0)), ]` This excludes rows where all entries for a gene are 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, using `rowSums`:

```
x[rowSums(x[1:3]) > 0, ]

  TTT TTA ATA  gene
1   0   0   1 gene1
2   1   1   0 gene2
3   0   1   0 gene3
```

Answer (score 3):

You might consider `dplyr` library. In this package, there is `filter` function that allows you to subset the rows with given conditions.

By adding `_if` behind the function, you can easily choose only the *numeric columns* using `is.numeric`.

```
x <- data.frame(TTT=c(0,1,0,0),
                TTA=c(0,1,1,0),
                ATA=c(1,0,0,0),
                gene=c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4"))

library(dplyr)
x %>%
  filter_if(is.numeric, any_vars(. != 0)) # any_vars() takes |

#>   TTT TTA ATA  gene
#> 1   0   0   1 gene1
#> 2   1   1   0 gene2
#> 3   0   1   0 gene3
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using data.table will be

```
x <- data.table(TTT=c(0,1,0,0),
                TTA=c(0,1,1,0),
                ATA=c(1,0,0,0),
                gene=c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4"))

x <- x[TTT != 0 | TTA != 0 | ATA != 0, ]
```

A more hard-coded option will be

```
x <- x[(TTT + TTA + ATA) != 0, ]
```